# HTTP Post Request from SSIS

Tags: http, file-upload, ssis

I need to run a HTTP Post request from within a SSIS integration package and am struggling to find anything that meets the requirements I need.

I have found various articles suggesting using the System.Net.WebClient namespace and using UploadFile. The issue with this is that the Post Request I need to run has a specific Access key which is hardcoded, but needs to be passed with the Post Request. I have added the Post Request I am trying to run below, if anyone has any suggestions or has any experience of this in the past it would be appreciated

```
POST /path/to/upload/script HTTP/1.0
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: My Client App v1.0 
Host:
https://bulksell.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?FileExchangeUpload
Content-type: multipart/form-data;
boundary=THIS_STRING_SEPARATES
Content-Length: 256
--THIS_STRING_SEPARATES
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="token"
12345678987654321
--THIS_STRING_SEPARATES
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file";
filename="listings.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv
... contents of listings.csv ...
--THIS_STRING_SEPARATES
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is wrong with issuing a post request using webclient? You can add custom header fields in `Header-Field: Header-Data` form like this `myWebClient.Headers.Add("Header-Field","Header-Data")` Just pay attention to restricted headers you can't set.

Comment: I didnt realise you could add headers, that should solve the problem though.